# Cada Palabra Grande en Mayúsculas: ¿anglicismo moderno o convención antigua?

Tags: gramática, historia, uso-de-mayúsculas

El impacto del inglés como una lengua franca en un mundo interconectado ciertamente ha afectado el idioma español.  Los anglicismos son notables en el vocabulario, pero yo personalmente los he notado especialmente en los títulos de canciones.  Por ejemplo:

- «11 PM» en vez de «11 p. m.» — prefiriendo el acrónimo del inglés americano
- «Fútbol & Rumba» en vez de «Fútbol y rumba» — prefiriendo el signo «&» del inglés
- «Puesto Pa’ Ti» en vez de «Puesto pa ti» — usando el [apóstrofo como en inglés](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19504/13065)
- «Que Calor» en vez de «Qué calor» — abandonando el acento en un frase común
- «Hasta el Amanecer» en vez de «Hasta el amanecer» — adoptando el uso de mayúsculas como en títulos ingleses (“title case”)

A pesar de que algunos de estos anglicismos son más horripilantes que los otros, la adopción del “title case” inglés es, por lejos, lo más extendido; simplemente abre el ranking latino en tu app de música para ver el perjuicio.  Tampoco es limitado a la cultura pop: hasta el APA (una organización estadounidense) [está fomentando esta convención](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/35315/13065) en contextos académicos.

El hecho es que [la RAE mantiene que](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/5680/13065):

> Se escriben con mayúscula la primera palabra del título de cualquier obra de creación (libros, películas, cuadros, esculturas, piezas musicales, programas de radio o televisión, etc.); el resto de las palabras que lo componen, salvo que se trate de nombres propios, deben escribirse con minúscula…

Mi pregunta requiere un conocimiento histórico de las convenciones de la lengua española. ¿Es lo que he descrito una convención antigua que surgió naturalmente dentro del mundo hispanohablante?  ¿O es un anglicismo moderno?

Comment: Gen-z: De acuerdo que es lamentable el disminuir de normas de uso correcto, en español y aún en el inglés. Seguí los "links" por varias páginas buscando algo que identifique quienes son el APA y qué autoridad supuestamente tienen, sin éxito. Probablemente lo ignoro por mis muchos años fuera de ambientes académicos. ¿Quienes son?

Comment: @cuevero American Psychological Association, pero han creado su propio [estilo estricto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APA_style) del formato y de la fraseología que es muy popular en el colegio igual como la universidad.

Comment: @cuevero To answer your other point in my more eloquent language: I don’t think I’m necessarily of the opinion that a language can be used “incorrectly” if the usage is widespread enough—even if it is not by the majority of the speakers—when that evolution is natural (I’m not saying this is/isn’t your stance here). However what I do believe is that it’s sad when one language or culture consumes another and extinguishes its native customs/conventions. A decade ago, if you said *estación*, I would have thought of «verano»; now I think «107.9 FM». Thankfully Spanish is not in danger of dying soon

Comment: No creo que todos esos fenómenos sean anglicismos. Como mínimo, la pérdida de las tildes es mayormente porque es más fácil teclear palabras sin tilde. El apóstrofo para abreviar palabras es más bien una regla italiana: en inglés, el apóstrofo sirve para combinar palabras.

Comment: Lo que explicaste sobre el apóstrofo me hace sentido. ¿Debería editar la pregunta? Por lo menos su uso en inglés ha tenido un poco de influencia. Pero no coincido contigo sobre las tildes en este caso; texting on a flip phone is one thing, but when you publish a song you’re practically choosing to omit it on purpose.

Comment: Gen-z: You're right. I try to avoid the term "correct" when I refer to languages, and rather take a descriptive view than prescriptive, more linguist than grammarian. It was a lapse I regret. Still, I try to adhere to the highest "standards" I can achieve, for the sake of clarity, but even more for sheer esthetic satisfaction, and appreciate it especially in published material.

Comment: @wimi I think we do use the apostrophe in English to indicate an omitted letter or letters. Didn't for did not for example. Once upon a time we wrote 'bus for omnibus and 'phone for telephone too. I think we drew the line at 'flu' for influenza though.

Comment: @cuevero Oh absolutely! I was not critiquing you at all. Believe me, it makes my skin crawl when I see stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede remontar hasta una edición incunable de las *Siete partidas* para ver que sólo la inicial del título llevaba mayúscula.

[image]

Igual, la primera edición del *Quijote* (1605), con los títulos de los capítulos.

[image]

Y una más reciente, de 1815.

[image]

Creo que eso es una manifestación más de agringamiento: el **gringañol**. NO estoy de acuerdo en que eso sea notable (digno de atención, ni menos sobresaliente). Sí se ve y se oye entre la gente agringada. ¿Por qué sucede? Porque consideran que todo lo gringo, por principio, es mejor, y eso va de par con la ignorancia de lo propio, incluido el español. Hasta donde sepa, las reglas del español no las ponen ni **la** APA ni ese compendio de errores de hecho, de lógica, de redacción y de ortografía que es un sitio de internet con ínfulas de enciclopedia, en el que cualquier iletrado escribe: la Wikipedia.

El agringamiento y el gringañol incluyen el gerundismo, como los cinco gerundios de la lista. Sí es correcto el apóstrofo, y no es uso del inglés, para indicar la elisión de una sílaba: *Puesto pa' ti*. Pero no es correcta la corrección que la sigue; debe ser: *¡Qué calor!*, con signos de exclamación; ahí no faltaba acento sino tilde, por falta de conocimiento de la ortografía. El "*ranking*" se llama escalafón o clasificación.

Eso de "*palabra grande*" está de antología.

Comment: Primero: prueba que sólo las iniciales de los títulos de obras antiguas llevaban mayúscula no prueba que en otros caso no se hiciera de manera distinta. Segundo: tu afirmación que «consideran que todo lo gringo, por principio, es mejor» me parece una suposición y fuera del tema. Tercero: corregir mi español así en negrita como si quieras que todo el mundo sepa que hablas el idioma mejor que yo es, según mi parecer, bien malcriado. Yo aprendí que los acrónimos de otros idiomas no se cambian y llevan «el», y además «ranking» es la traducción de *charts* que recomienda WordReference.

Comment: @gen-ℤreadytoperish es *la* APA porque es la *asociación*.  Si aprendiste que estos siempre llevan *el*, pues, aprendiste (o te enseñaron) mal.  La NASA, la ONU, la OTAN. Como medievalista y aurisecularista, puedo confirmar que las normas del uso entre mayúscula y minúscula poco han cambiado tras los siglos y las imágenes presentadas son absolutamente representativas del entonces uso corriente y que jamás he visto una secuencia extendida de texto en la que las letras iniciales de cada palabra se ponga en mayúscula y el resto en minúscula.  Es la mar de moderno.